# ASP.Net Sessions unexpectedly terminating

Tags: c#, session, iis, amazon-ec2, asp.net-4.0

I have a web application that suddenly started terminating sessions unexpectedly.  I've enabled logging of app pool recycling events via the IIS Manager UI, the healthMonitoring in the global web.config and added logging code to the Application_End event in global asax, but I don't see any logs generated.  So, I don't think it's app pool or app domain recycling.  My app pool idle timeout is 300 minutes and it's not set on a fixed recycling schedule anyway.

My session timeout and forms auth timeout are 180 minutes.  But even if the user is fully active, their session still seems to get kicked out.

I'm working on Windows Server 2008 R2 on Amazon EC2 with an ASP.Net 4.0 web application.  Session is InProc on a single server (no web farm/garden). I don't have any antivirus that could be updating files, and I don't see any updates to config files or binaries in my application folders. I even tried launching an instance with more RAM in case IIS was forcing sessions out of memory for using too much up.

Any ideas where to look next?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?   I'm running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Though its not a direct answer, I'd recommend using the StateServer mode to handle sessions and see if that solves the problem.

Just enable the StateServer service on the same machine and change your web.config file accordingly. It might give you a clue to your original problem.